# sub-examples in amsthm

Tags: amsthm

I'm using the newtheorem macro in amsthm for example environments. Is there a way for a sub-example? I don't need anything fancy like indenting, just a new counter level would do. So that within say Example 4, a few sub-examples would be numbered as Example 4.1, Example 4.2, etc. Maybe I could just do something with the counter in that area of the document?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}

\begin{example} first example
\end{example}

\begin{example} second example. Here are situations where this occurs.
\end{example}

%\begin{subexample} first sub-example of second example
%\end{subexample}

%\begin{subexample} second sub-example of second example
%\end{subexample}

\begin{example} third example
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `subexample` using the `amsthm` commands as normal.

Afterwards, issue `\counterwithin{subexample}{example}`, which would make the counter for subexample subordinate to that for example.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify this "sub-numbering" via a final/closing optional argument in `\newtheorem{<theorem>}[<sibling counter>]{<title>}[<sub-counter>]` (where the optional arguments are mutually exclusive; that is, you can't use both):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{subexample}{Example}[example]% subexample is a sub-counter to example

\begin{document}

\begin{example} first example
\end{example}

\begin{example} second example. Here are situations where this occurs.
\end{example}

\begin{subexample} first sub-example of second example
\end{subexample}

\begin{subexample} second sub-example of second example
\end{subexample}

\begin{example} third example
\end{example}

\end{document}
```